# How to cut commission from the transaction with minimal amount of fees

Tags: web3js, dapps, payments

I'm trying to build a crypto payment provider, and would like to cut a commission and keep the fees minimal on my customer

consider the transaction is from address A (the buyer) to address B (the seller or my customer)

What's the best solution to cut the commission to my address C

Comment: Can you please share your current implementation? It will be helpful for us If you provide any code for reference.

Comment: @snsakib I am still newbie in Web3, still no implementation, asking about the best solution or the best practice

Answer (score 0):

There may be lots of best practices, but I know the followings:

1. Off-chain transactions: You can conduct transactions on a secondary layer outside the main blockchain network. This way, you can minimize the number of transactions on the main blockchain, thus reducing fees.
2. Batch processing: Instead of processing each transaction individually, you can batch multiple transactions together and submit them as a single transaction on the blockchain.